# How do you add to a custom function such as String => Int

Tags: scala

Not quite sure on the wording of the title but what I'm trying to do is extend an environment defined as type `Environment = String => Int`
I've got this from the [Scala tutorial for java programmers.](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-for-java-programmers.html) (Case Classes and Pattern Matching)

So i've got a function which can lookup in this environment.

```
type Environment = String => Int

val env: Environment = { case "x" => 5 }

def lookupEnv(env: Environment, x:String): Int =
{
     env(x)
}

def extendEnv(env: Environment, x:String, v:Int)
{
    ????
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "extend?" I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: FYI: don't forget the `=` on your `def` when you mean to return something. If you omit it, the method is assumed by the compiler to be a `Unit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
def extendEnv(env: Environment, x:String, v:Int): Environment = 
   (y: String) => if (y == x) v else env(y)
```

See the description of this syntax under "anonymous functions" of the tutorial. Note that

1. this will "replace" a value for `x` in `env` if there already was one. Of course, you can still access it in `env` itself, which hasn't changed.
2. this isn't a particularly *good* representation for environments. E.g. if you add enough variables, you'll get stack overflows.